# Retrieving variable value from a powershell script

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, task-scheduler

I need to run the below script with Task scheduler after every 15 min (to refresh the token before it expires). I have a another script which would use the 'Token value' by calling the function 'getToken'.

Problem is, when I run the script with task it does not save the variable $token as powershell session is created just for the task. When script being executed without the task, I can use 'getToken' value. Creating a global variable did not help/

Is there a solution to this or any other way around?

```
$refreshTokenBody = @{  grant_type = 'refresh_token'
                    client_id = 'clientID'
                    refresh_token= 'TokenNumber123124'}

$tokenRefresh = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Uri "https://url.com" -Body $refreshTokenBody 
$Global:token = $($tokenRefresh.access_token)

Function getToken{ 
       return $token
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell only persists variables throughout the course of the script's execution. You should look at writing the variable out somehow for later reuse. Personally I like the registry for this but the file system is also a valid choice.

```
$Config = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\yourregkey"
# Write to registry with this.
New-ItemProperty $Config -Name <Variable Name Here>  -Value <value here> -Type string -Force
# Read from registry with this. 
$ReadFromReg =  $Config.<Variable Name Here>
```